# Can't Dismiss Progress Dialog in android

Tags: android

How to Dismiss Progress Dialog in android after completion of Background Process ?

I had tried on Google but not get specific solution as i want.

Here is my code :

```
private void next() {

    String url = "http://10.0.2.2/final/studentrecord.php";
    FetchDataTask task = new FetchDataTask(url);


    dialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", "Fetching StudentList from Server...", true, true);


    task.execute(url);

}
```

How can i do this ?

Comment: try this `dialog.dismiss()` after your process complete

Comment: use `dialog.dismiss()` in `onPostExecute` method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure your dialog is accessible even after completion of task :-

you should do like this :-

create dialog in `onPreExecute()`

and dismiss it using `dialog.dismiss()` in `onPostExecute()`

Comment: i am not Vilen Melkumyan .. you have accepted my answer instead of his

Answer (score 1):

Use Handler and dialog.dismiss();

Define Handler object in your activity, from background post a message to handler with `handler.sendMessage(msg);`
and in activity where your dialog is defined implement Handler.Callback's handleMessage method

e.g. if you send message to handler like

```
Message msg = new Message();
    msg.what = 1;
    handler.sendMessage(msg);
```

then in handleMessage method

```
@Override
public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
    if (msg.what == 1) {
        dialog.dismiss(); 
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in the post execute type

```
 dialog.dismiss()
```

Comment: I accepts both of your answers. your ans is correct also. so,thank you, too.